# Body width smaller than one of my containers HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I finished writing my code for an beginners html/css project, but I learned soon after, that my main parent container that holds two other smaller containers needs to be at 960px width. The smaller one inside have to be 650px and 270px. I have no problems when I change the width of the two smaller ones, but when I change the parent container width to 960, the content just seem to cut off about 2/3 of the way in the browser. I have a heading section above and footer section below and they stretch across the entire browser. I am not sure why my main parent container does that. The `<body>` that holds all of the code, is listed as having a width of 831 and a height of 1060 or something. Why is my body smaller than the container? My pages look perfect when I do not set the width of the parent container to 960px.

```css
section.sidebar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
h1.HeadOne {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: 135px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  float: left;
}
section.main {
  width: 960px;
  background-image: url(../images/vichy.png);
  border-top: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul {
  margin-left: 575px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 23px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
a.blue:hover {
  color: blue;
}
a.contact:hover {
  color: orange;
}
a:link {
  color: orange;
}
a:hover {
  color: green;
}
a.contact {
  border-left: solid;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: #A9A9A9;
  border-width: thin;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#Profile {
  width: 190px;
  height: 160px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
#Profile:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-160deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-160deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-160deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-160deg);
  transform: rotate(-160deg);
}
.mainDiv {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  width: 650px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
h1.mainDivH1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4aaaa5;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: #cccccc;
}
p {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p.p2 {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
div.DivConnect {
  float: left;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  background-color: white;
  width: 270px;
  height: 160px;
  */ padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
h2.ConnectHeader {
  text-align: left;
  color: #4aaaa5;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
ol.ConnectList {
  border-top: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 19px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
li.connectLI {
  float: left;
}
#facebook {
  width: 58px;
}
#facebook:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#linked {
  width: 58px;
}
#linked:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
#twitter {
  width: 58px;
}
#twitter:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-160deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-160deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-160deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-160deg);
  transform: rotate(-160deg);
}
footer.foot {
  height: 60px;
  border-color: black;
  /*border-width: medium;*/
  border-top: solid;
  border-top-width: 8px;
  background-color: #666666;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
form {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font-family: 'Georgia', Times, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
input {
  width: 580px;
}
h3 {
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'Georgia', Times, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
h1.PortfolioH1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4aaaa5;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: #cccccc;
}
div.PortIm1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  top: 33px;
  left: 35px;
}
#Pic1 {
  width: 275px;
  height: 170px;
  margin-right: -50px;
}
#Pic1:hover {
  outline: 5px solid green;
  outline-offset: 10px;
}
div.mainDivPortfolio {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  height: 720px;
  width: 650px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Georgia, serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  width: 275px;
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div.PortIm2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  left: 355px;
  top: -140px;
  bottom: 170px;
}
#Pic2 {
  width: 275px;
  height: 170px;
}
#Pic2:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div.PortIm3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  left: 355px;
  top: -100px;
}
#Pic3 {
  width: 275px;
  height: 170px;
}
#Pic3:hover {
  outline: thin solid orange;
  outline-offset: 10px;
}
div.PortIm4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  bottom: 273px;
  right: -35px;
}
#Pic4 {
  width: 275px;
  height: 170px;
}
#Pic4:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
div.PortIm5 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 235px;
  left: 35px;
}
#Pic5 {
  width: 275px;
  height: 170px;
}
#Pic5:hover {
  outline: medium solid yellow;
  outline-offset: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="Sidebar">
  <h1 class="HeadOne">Name</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="file:///C:/Users/hen/Desktop/Camp/assignments/Basic-Portfolio/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      <!--CHANGE THE LINKS TO THE CORRECT WEBPAGES-->
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="contact" href="file:///C:/Users/hen/Desktop/Camp/assignments/Basic-Portfolio/contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="blue" href="file:///C:/Users/hen/Desktop/Camp/assignments/Basic-Portfolio/index.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="main">
  <div class="mainDiv">
    <h1 class="mainDivH1">About Me</h1>
    <img id="Profile" src="assets/images/PortfolioPicture.jpg" alt="Mad Hatter" />
    <p>Content.....</p>
    <p class="p2">Content.....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="DivConnect">
    <h2 class="ConnectHeader"> Connect with Me </h2>
    <ol class="ConnectList">
      <li class="connectLI">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
          <img id="facebook" src="assets/images/1474864409_facebook.png" alt="face" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="connectLI">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=en" target="_blank">
          <img id="twitter" src="assets/images/1474864502_Twitter_icon.png" alt="twitt" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="connectLI">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank">
          <img id="linked" src="assets/images/1474864458_linkedin_circle_black.png" alt="linkedin" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</section>
<footer class=f oot>
  &copy; Copyright 2016 Anonymous
</footer>
```

Comment: The `body` has the same width as the window, and its contents simply overflow out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have added margins in every div and have added width to div elements too and now the screen has been occupied with the [small-div-width] + [margins] and this area is greater than 960px that's why when you give manual width to the main div the smaller elements cut-off

Comment: I figured out the problem. The background image was included in the class I made 960px, which is why it wasnt spanning across the entire browser and cutting off. I had to make a separate parent container that held 960px container and set the backbround image in it, not in the 960px container.